# Why is my maven not picking up my maven profile?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I want to run a custom piece of work that requires the use of some maven profiles.

In the past; this has worked fine, but for some reason it's just suddenly decided to stop reading the profile at all; even though it's there...

So in my settings.xml file for GLOBAL Maven (i.e C:/) I have the following set up: (Secure data redacted for obvious reasons)

```
<server>
  <id>[MY-ID]</id>
  <username>[MY-USERNAME]</username>
  <password>[MY-PASSWORD]</password>
</server>

....

<profile>
  <id>[MY-PROFILE-ID]</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>mulesoft</id>
      <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>[ANOTHER-PROFILE-ID]</id>
      <url>[COMPANY-URL]</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>[ANOTHER-PROFILE-ID]</id>
      <url>[COMPANY-URL]</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>[ANOTHER-PROFILE-ID]</id>
      <url>[COMPANY-URL]</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>bintray-vgs</id>
      <url>https://dl.bintray.com/vg/vgs-oss</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>cdversion</id>
      <url>https://github.com/beaverworks/cdversion-maven-extension/raw/repository</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>[ANOTHER-PROFILE-ID]</id>
      <url>[COMPANY-URL]</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```

I've applied these settings in Eclipse and also tried running
`mvn -P [MY-PROFILE-ID] clean package`

but to no avail, I see the same error time and time again:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project [MY-INSTALLATION-PROJECT]: Could not resolve dependencies for project [MY-INSTALLATION-PROJECT]: Failed to collect dependencies at [MAVEN-CUSTOM-SECURE-COMPANY-PACKAGE] -> [MAVEN-CUSTOM-SECURE-COMPANY-PACKAGE]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for [MAVEN-CUSTOM-SECURE-COMPANY-PACKAGE]: Could not transfer artifact [MAVEN-CUSTOM-SECURE-COMPANY-PACKAGE] from/to salient [COMPANY-URL]: Access denied to: [MAVEN-CUSTOM-SECURE-COMPANY-PACKAGE] -> [Help 1]
```

When I run this with errors turned on (-e) I can see that it's failing due to a 403, which would indicate to me it's not picking up the profile correctly:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: [COMPANY-CUSTOM-MAVEN-PACKAGE]
```

Comment: From your logs I'm not sure, in fact, if maven is trying to contact the repositories defined in the profile. 403 looks like an error you would get if you contact the right server but with wrong credentials.

Comment: @FabioF. I copied the wrong log error. Updated with the correct one.

Comment: Ok, I got it. remove the server settings from `settings.xml` and retry. it should work.

Comment: Try to use wget to see if the credentials are correct `wget --user=username --password=password "http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=<group>&a=<artifact>&v=<version>&r=snapshots"
`

Comment: @FabioF. - They are

Comment: @Raisus are you 100% sure that username and password in xml are the same you're testing with wget? Do you have other xml profiles somewhere else and maybe is using those other one?

Comment: @FabioF. I am 100% certain of it.

Eclipse has some in-built profiles, but I've set it up that for the particular workspace, it only uses the profile in _global_ settings.xml